# Web Service - PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf, wcf-security

For proof of concept and learning purposes, I'm trying to do the most simple possible use of SecurityAction.Demand as follows:

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = @"MyDomain\MyGroup")]
public string GetData(int value)
{
    return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
}
```

I wrote a console test program, and I'm getting the System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAccessDeniedException, even though I'm a member of the group specified above.

I've read a lot of docs and blogs which have left me totally confused.  I seem to be getting lost in the number of permutations of things to try.

Questions:

1. Do I need to publish to IIS instead of using Cassini inside Visual Studio?
2. Does it work only with wsHttpBinding?  I created a .NET console test program, added a service-reference and it defaulted to basicHttpBinding, even though some blogs and examples I was looking indicated that a Service Reference should be wsHttpBinding.
3. What are the minimum changes to the binding file to get this to work. I know have to change some parms to set security mode to Windows, but first I need to make sure I'm in the proper bindings (thus question #2 above).

Comment: Depending on the version of windows you are running on you may need to run with elevated permissions

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: No idea, that was 2 or 3 contracts ago.